# How to reduce size of app for Google Play Console (I am using Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console

I've made an app but it has exceeded the 150 mb limit of Google Play Console. My app is very simple and so it can't be because my app is too complicated. I have a lot of audio files on my app, so that is why. How do bigger apps get around this? I have already made an Android App Bundle. I have heard about APK Expansion Files. Can someone explain that? Thanks

Comment: I think the only solution to my problem is to keep the audio files in an asset pack since I need all of the resources. Can someone explain how to do this and/or direct me to a helpful article or something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are some things you should try to reduce your app's size:

1. First of all, try to **breakdown your apk** using [Apk Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html).
2. Then try using **ProGuard** or **R8**. Find more info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code).
3. Use **shrinkResources** attribute in the Gradle to remove all the resources which are not being used anywhere in the project.
4. Use **resConfigs** to remove the localized resources which are not needed.

A nice article explaining most of the above can be found [here](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-you-can-decrease-application-size-by-60-in-only-5-minutes-47eff3e7874e).

Other things you should try, as stated [here](https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-reduce-apk-size-in-android-2f3713d2d662), are the following:

1. Try to **remove unused resources**
2. Investigate **Lint** warnings for useless code removals
3. Reduce the libraries you use as much as possible, **compile only necessary libraries**.
4. Use scalable drawable objects, for example **use SVG image files** instead of **PNG** or **JPEG**. If you cannot avoid using these types of image files, then you should **compress images** with tools like [tinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/).
5. **Reuse code** as much as possible, don't write unecessary duplicated code.